# Searching file names from list optimisation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to find files in a folder and move them into their seperate destination folders. I have a column of FILENAME next to a column of the respective FOLDER. The files are names as FILENAME_Ver_X and there should be 2 of each in the folder of different file types.

At the moment my code goes through each file, reads if it contains the FILENAME string and if so moves it to the folder. However this is quite slow as there is a massive number of files so I was wondering if there was a better way to search through it all.

```
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(Viewables)
Do While r <= maxRows
d = Rng(r, 1) & "_Ver_"
e = Rng(r, 2)
For Each f1 In objFolder.Files
    If InStr(1, Left(f1.Name, Len(d)), d) > 0 Then
    tPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & e & "\"
    fso.MoveFile (Viewables & f1.Name), tPath

    End If
Next
r = r + 1
Loop
```

Comment: You can use the vb built in NAME command to move files: Name Viewables & filename as tpath & filename  would move filename from viewables to tpath

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just use vba to cycle through folder but then use windows level move command once per folder

The move command would allow wild cards so the vba could supply the original path and the move command logic

So you end up running the  move command once per folder

You could get log the path and count of files in path before and after for auditing